Using pandas to find a row within the range of a before given number
I have a csv file with 3 columns, a minimum, maximum value and a set_value.
My goal is to use pandas to read the 3 columns, take the pre-existing number, check if it's within one of the ranges (should always be within one so I didn't add a scenario where it isn't), then turns the pre-existing number into the set_value from the csv file.
I wrote the code as is, reads the file, each row is defined at the same time as checking the ranges. Then it just converts the angular_offset we had from before.
csv_path_ang = (*directory*)
df_ang = pandas.read_csv(csv_path_ang)

df_ang['set_value'] = df_ang[(df_ang['minimum'] <= angular_offset) & (df_ang['maximum'] >= angular_offset)]
angular_offset = df_ang['set_value']

I keep getting this error:

pandas.parser.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 3, saw 3

I'm assuming this is cause the 'set_value' either isn't being read properly or just isn't being used. I kept trying different solutions but this is the closest I got to an actual solution and then I got this error.
I think at one point I managed to get a working version of this but I cant for the love of me replicate it, as I'm barely experienced with pandas and its pretty important that I do this quickly so any help would be greatly appreciated.

This question is similar to: pandas.parser.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Please provide a [mre] of your input data and the exact matching expected output. It however looks like you don't even read the file, so your issue most likely doesn't have anything to do with the logic to filter your values.

@Rishabh_KT , the solutions from that question did nothing to help with my issue, the only thing that changed was that when it ignored the error it went through and gave me the same error for all 100 rows.
@mozway i just deleted the actual directory, i dont have logs setup for the offset i get here but right after calculating the value thats right before the code i posted it gives me this:
`GEOMETRY:[119.1941605839416, 121.40145985401459]
Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 3, saw 3
2024-07-17 15:29:23,083 Error with File
:29:23,084 Finished!
Errors: 1`
